# Swift Event catched and know?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a class in my project. And the class connects to a server and a message is sent to the server by calling a send() function from the `UIViewController`.

The Server is receiving and responds by sending a message back. My StreamDelegate (Connection) gets the Event and I receive the message. Now the problem. After sending the message by pressing a button in the UI I want to show the response in a textView or label. But how do I get the message from the Connection class to the ViewController? And what to do with the UI. I want the user to wait and not to do other stuff (Maybe checking a login).

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use loading indicator:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Loading \n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)

let spinnerIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)

spinnerIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: 135.0, y: 65.5)
spinnerIndicator.color = UIColor.black
spinnerIndicator.startAnimating()

alertController.view.addSubview(spinnerIndicator)
self.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And when You got your message back, just use:

```
alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
```

to dismiss it.
During the time loading indicator is shown, User cannot click or do anything.